# Blender 2.8 Moving Vertices With G + X, Y, or Z Generates Odd Angles

Tags: modeling

[image]

I started working on a low poly model today and have run into trouble with the move tool. Normally, I press g + x, y, or z, and then the vertices snap to the axis I chose. However, for some reason now whenever I press g and one of the three axes, it no longer snaps to the axis I chose but rather some odd diagonal. I'm extremely new to blender so any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you've set your transform orientations to Normals. Try settings it back to global. That should fix it

[image: transform orientation normal to global]

Comment: Thank you very much I would've never caught that.